# English equivalent of tsundere

Tags: translation, loanwords, japanese

I wonder if anyone has an approximation for the Japanese “tsundere”?

> Tsundere (ツンデレ, pronounced [tsɯndeɽe]) is a Japanese character development process that describes a person who is initially cold and even hostile towards another person before gradually showing their warm side over time.
>
> [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere)

About the closest I can come is “hate to love” but I wonder if there’s something more succinct?

Answer (score 2):

The related idioms for "gradually showing a warm and caring side over time" are:

> - ***warm (up) to somebody***: to start to like someone: 
>   *I wasn't sure about Sarah at first, but I warmed to her after we'd been out together a few times.* [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/warm-to-sb)
> - ***grow on someone***: if something or someone grows on you, you start to like them more [*Macmillan*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grow-on)

However, I don't think there is an exact equivalent in English to describe the character. *[Tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Tsundere)* offers some alternatives for *tsundere* though:

> Punchy Love, Oranyan, Hot And Cold, Bitter Sweet Heart, Affectionate Spitfire, Mood Swinging Sweetheart, Sweet And Sour Personality, Sugar And Fire Personality
>
> <sub>* Oranyan is sometimes used to refer to a male tsundere character - incorrectly since it means the complete opposite.</sub>

Additionally, *tsundere* appears as an English word in *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsundere)* and it is already used as a loan word:

> *(chiefly Japanese media)* A fictional character who fits the archetype of being cold and even hostile towards another person before gradually showing a warm and caring side over time.

Comment: Suggest adding the *softening* of someone *hard-hearted.*  It's a common trope, though.  I still wonder if there's a lit crit name for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the english idiom equivalent would be ***Heart of Gold***

Comment: More like a [jerk with a heart of gold](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JerkWithAHeartOfGold).

Comment: I think, from TV tropes it would be [Hidden Heart Of Gold](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenHeartOfGold)